# global catch in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have MySQL script which starts with query which extracts data from database, then this data is processed and in the final step i want to write processed data back to the database. The thing is, every time I send query to database i would like to have a try-catch function to handle error with the same type of exception handling, e.g

```
try
{
    server connections, queries, etc .
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '<p class="error">Server error! please try again later!</p>';
    echo '<a href="index.php">Return to Home Page</a>';
    // echo '<br/><p>Developer message: '.$e.'</p>';
    exit();
}
...
functions, etc .
...
try
{
    server connections, queries, etc .
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo '<p class="error">Server error! please try again later!</p>';
    echo '<a href="index.php">Return to Home Page</a>';
    // echo '<br/><p>Developer message: '.$e.'</p>';
    exit();
}
```

The thing is I would like to avoid the redundancy of the code and write one global 'catch' to handle all 'try' instances. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: have you heard about indenting?

Comment: Have you heard of the manual [The mysqli API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [The PDO API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) The PDO API comes with its own built in mechanism for using Exceptions so that is where I suggest you start

Comment: Not quite what you're after but you could extend the base `Exception` class to be something more specific, or catch other specific exceptions, depending on what type of exception is thrown and use a single try block with several catch blocks; e.g. `try { ... } catch(PDOException $exPDO) { ... } catch (OtherException $exOther) { ... } catch (Exception $ex) { ... }`

Comment: This may also be of use to you http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php

Comment: If you're just catching exceptions to show a message to a user you could probably just not bother with `try {} catch {}` blocks and just fallback to the PHP global exception handling strategies (which you could define differently per environment).

Answer (score 8):

The following is usually the typical way to remove duplicated code in a procedural style.

```
function handleException($e) {
    echo '<p class="error">Server error! please try again later!</p>';
    echo '<a href="index.php">Return to Home Page</a>';        
    exit();
}

try {
    server connections, queries, etc.
}
catch (Exception $e)     {
     handleException($e);
}
...
functions, etc.
...
try {
    server connections, queries, etc.
}
catch (Exception $e) {
      handleException($e);
}
```

Now in reality, you don't really need to handling all exceptions in PHP unless you can recover from them or you need to do something special with them. If you just want to show an error then set a global catch-all handler on your app's startup and use that as a default unless otherwise specified.

New code:

```
set_exception_handler(function ($e) {
   echo '<p class="error">Server error! please try again later!</p>';
   echo '<a href="index.php">Return to Home Page</a>';        
   exit();
});

server connections, queries, etc.
...
functions, etc.
...

server connections, queries, etc.
```

Comment: +1 just for _Now in reality, you don't really need to handling all exceptions  in PHP unless you can recover from them_